# Loading outside class with StandardAutoloader in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework

In my ZendSkeletonApplication I have module called "Tasks". This is my dir tree

```
Tasks
--config
--src
-----Tasks
-------Controler
---------Scraper.php
-------Vendor
----------Fetch.php
-- view
module.php
```

Scraper Controller

```
<?php

namespace Tasks\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class ScraperController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo \Tasks\Vendor\Fetch();
        return new ViewModel();
    }


}
```

and my module.php

```
<?php
namespace Tasks;

class Module
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__   => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                    'Tasks\Vendor'  => __DIR__ . '/src/Tasks/Vendor',
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

It this module is getting me error, when I am trying to load \Tasks\Vendor\Fetch(). What I am doing wrong?

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function Tasks\Vendor\Fetch() in /var/www/similarweb.zend/module/Tasks/src/Tasks/Controller/ScraperController.php on line 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen here. If `Tasks\Vendor\Fetch` is a class, you either need to create an instance of it and then call one of it's methods:

```
$fetch = new \Tasks\Vendor\Fetch();
$fetch->something();
```

or if it's a static method, call it statically:

```
\Tasks\Vendor\Fetch::something();
```